# Can't run the site on plesk due to stored procedure error

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, database, plesk

I am facing a bit of a problem regarding website uploading on plesk. The problem is I have uploaded my mvc site along with database on plesk control panel, but I get a stored procedure error, i.e. stored procedure is not found. Please if you have some better solution then please let me know and send the solution. Please send the immediate solution as soon as possible will be thankful heartily.

Comment: if it says the stored procedure doesn't exist, then probably you didn't deploy your stored procedure, and/or your're connecting to the wrong database. Did you check those things? We can't help you with checking your deployment or environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that database user does not have permissions to execute stored procedures. Due to security reasons, Plesk does not grant such permissions by default nor provide a functionality to grant permissions on a stored procedure to an existing user.

This can be performed [via MSSQL Management Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/grant-permissions-on-a-stored-procedure), for example.